# Access variables from within the callback function of the 'each' function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel `->each()` function inside a loop.

I want to be able to get at the loop variables from within the each function.

```
    foreach ($stringsArray as $string) {
        if (!empty($string)) {
            DBModel::all()->each(function (DBModel $model) {
                    global $string;
                    // $string at this point is nothing/undefined
```

How can I access `$string` from within the `->each()` function?

This is using laravel 4.2.

With the current code `$string` is undefined (with or without the `global` directive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `use` keyword to use it in the anonymous scope
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
$example = function () use ($message) {
        var_dump($message);
};

$example();
```